# WinRT - App bar not appearing when I tap the ellipses

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-rt, winrt-async

I'm trying to get my app bar to appear when I tap the 3 dots at the bottom of the screen, but when I do so it doesn't happen. Anyone know why & how this problem can be rectified?

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Name="pageRoot"
    x:Class="HP.MainPage"
    DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Exits_Expert_London_Lite.Lines_and_Stations.WC"
    xmlns:common="using:Exits_Expert_London_Lite.Common"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:q42controls="using:Q42.WinRT.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">    

    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

        <Grid Name="CustomAppBarRoot" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Loaded="CustomAppBarRoot_OnLoaded"
          ManipulationMode="TranslateY"
          ManipulationDelta="CustomAppBarRoot_OnManipulationDelta"
          ManipulationCompleted="CustomAppBarRoot_OnManipulationCompleted"
          Tapped="CustomAppBarRoot_OnTapped">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>

            <Grid.Background>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.5"></SolidColorBrush>
            </Grid.Background>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Name="DotsTextBlock" FontSize="28" Text="..." HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
                    Margin="0 0 15 0" Tapped="DotsTextBlock_OnTapped" Width="50" Height="50" TextAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="0" X="11"/>
                </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
            </TextBlock>

            <StackPanel Name="ButtonsStackPanel" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal">
                <AppBarButton Label="tfg" Icon="Add"/>
                <AppBarButton Label="tfg" Icon="Add"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>

        <Hub>
            <Hub.Header>
                <!-- Back button and page title -->
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button  x:Name="backButton" Margin="-1,-1,39,0" Command="{Binding NavigationHelper.GoBackCommand, ElementName=pageRoot}"
                        Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        AutomationProperties.Name="Back"
                        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="BackButton"
                        AutomationProperties.ItemType="Navigation Button"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="Page name" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" 
                        IsHitTestVisible="false" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                </Grid>
            </Hub.Header>

            <HubSection Width="800" Padding="40,50,0,0">
                <HubSection.Header>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="hub section 1" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </HubSection.Header>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,5" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                                <Run Text="Hello World"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
        </Hub>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

**MainPage.cs**

```
using HP.Common;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Animation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The Hub Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=321224

namespace HP
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Tapped += Page_OnTapped;
        }

        private void Page_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs tappedRoutedEventArgs)
        {
            if ( isAppBarShown )
                HideCustomAppBar();
        }

        #region custom app bar

        private Storyboard hideCustomAppBarStoryboard;
        private Storyboard showCustomAppBarStoryboard;
        private Size appBarSize;
        private Size appBarButtonsSize;
        private bool isAppBarShown = true;

        private void CustomAppBarRoot_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            appBarSize = new Size(CustomAppBarRoot.ActualWidth, CustomAppBarRoot.ActualHeight);
            appBarButtonsSize = new Size(ButtonsStackPanel.ActualWidth, ButtonsStackPanel.ActualHeight);
            InitializeStoryboards();

            HideCustomAppBar();
        }

        private void ShowCustomAppBar()
        {
            isAppBarShown = true;
            showCustomAppBarStoryboard.Begin();
        }

        private void HideCustomAppBar()
        {
            isAppBarShown = false;
            hideCustomAppBarStoryboard.Begin();
        }

        private void DotsTextBlock_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (isAppBarShown)
                HideCustomAppBar();
            else
                ShowCustomAppBar();
        }

        private void InitializeStoryboards()
        {
            hideCustomAppBarStoryboard = new Storyboard();
            showCustomAppBarStoryboard = new Storyboard();

            var showDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                EasingFunction = new CircleEase() {EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut},
                To = 0,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
            };
            var hideDoubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                EasingFunction = new CubicEase() {EasingMode = EasingMode.EaseInOut},
                To = appBarButtonsSize.Height,
                Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200))
            };
            hideCustomAppBarStoryboard.Children.Add(hideDoubleAnimation);
            showCustomAppBarStoryboard.Children.Add(showDoubleAnimation);

            Storyboard.SetTarget(hideCustomAppBarStoryboard, CustomAppBarRoot);
            Storyboard.SetTarget(showCustomAppBarStoryboard, CustomAppBarRoot);
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(showCustomAppBarStoryboard, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(hideCustomAppBarStoryboard, "(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TranslateTransform.Y)");
        }

        #endregion

        private void CustomAppBarRoot_OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var translateTransform = (CustomAppBarRoot.RenderTransform as TranslateTransform);

            double newY = e.Delta.Translation.Y + translateTransform.Y;
            translateTransform.Y = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(newY, appBarButtonsSize.Height));
        }

        private void CustomAppBarRoot_OnManipulationCompleted(object sender, ManipulationCompletedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // if small appbar-position changes are made app bar should back to previous position, just like in windows phone
            if (Math.Abs(e.Cumulative.Translation.Y) < 20)
                isAppBarShown = !isAppBarShown;

            if (!isAppBarShown)
                ShowCustomAppBar();
            else
                HideCustomAppBar();
        }

        private void CustomAppBarRoot_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true; // prevents raising Page.Tapped event so appbar won't be closed on AppBar-area tap
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your CustomAppBarRoot Grid after the Hub control so it renders on top. As is, the Hub control covers the CustomAppBarRoot so clicks on the ellipses go to the Hub not to the DotsTextBlock. If you give the Hub a background colour for testing this is quite obvious (leave the Background off for production):

```
<Hub Background="Magenta">
```

You could also raise the CustomAppBarRoot in the Z-order by applying the [Canvas.ZIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.canvas.zindex.aspx) property; however, since your CustomAppBarRoot isn't in a Canvas this is an off-label use so I'd prefer placing the CustomAppBarRoot after the Hub in the Xaml:

```
 <Grid Name="CustomAppBarRoot" Canvas.ZIndex="100" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Loaded="CustomAppBarRoot_OnLoaded"
```

There is a Segoe UI Symbol for the "More" ellipses at Unicode 0xe10c that you might use rather than using a string of periods:

```
<TextBlock Name="DotsTextBlock" Text="&#xe10c;" FontSize="14" FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Margin="0 0 15 0" Tapped="DotsTextBlock_OnTapped" Width="50" Height="50" TextAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform Y="0" X="11"/>
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```